# I am trying to place my notebook in a specific directory on Kaggle

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kaggle

As you can see, the code on the left references a specific directory structure. So, to get this to work, I want to place this notebook in a specific directory. That directory is "src", which you see on the right. I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Can someone please help out?

[image: Kaggle code snippet]